# What's the name of the song in Naruto Shippuden that plays in episode 203 at 11:22?

Tags: naruto, music

What's the name of the song in Naruto Shippuden that plays in episode 203 at 11:22? The moment Sasuke created the Susano'o to defend himself from Gaara, Temari, Darui and Kankuro.

https://youtu.be/_JZURm4lh58

Answer (score 0):

The song you refer to is called "Sasuke's Ninja Way" (サスケの忍道, Sasuke no Nindō).

Listen here: https://youtu.be/AastZeIJJDA